# Two queues, one with concurrency 1 another with concurrency 3

Tags: javascript, node.js, concurrency, queue, async.js

I have this situation with:

```
const q1 = async.queue((task,cb) => task(cb), 1);
const q2 = async.queue((task,cb) => task(cb), 3);
```

basically, the situation is - if I can get a lock on q1, I can process up to 3 things concurrently in q2. Aka, most things in my program have to run serially, but certainly things can run in parallel, but only if they acquire a "lock" on q1 first. However, writing this turns out to be much harder than expected. I think it's akin to the reader/write locking problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock

In other words, I can only process things in q2 if I have a lock on q1. One problem with implementing this, is if I always have to acquire a lock on q1 in the critical section of q2, then I won't be able to use a higher concurrency level in q2, it will always be serial.

The only idea I have right now is to flip a boolean, something like this:

```
let q2HasLock = false;

if(q2hasLock === true){
  q2.push(cb => ...);
}
else{
  q1.push(cb => ...);
}
```

then I can use this:

```
q2.drain = () => {
   q2HasLock = false;
};
```

but the remaining part is I don't know how/when to flip `q2HasLock` to `true`. Hopefully you understand the problem/idea. Another problem with this implementation, is that requests to push to q2 could starve requests that are going to q1, so I could do this:

```
let q2HasLock = false, count = 0 ;

if(q2hasLock === true && count < 3){
  count++;
  q2.push(cb => ...);
}
else{
  q1.push(cb => ...);
}

q2.drain = () => {
   count = 0;
   q2HasLock = false;
};
```

This is getting hairy - I would like to implement this as simply as possible!

Comment: Could you please elaborate what kind of tasks the queues will execute? As you probably know, JS is single-threaded, with the exception for any asynchronous operation like file or network I/O which are delegated to `libuv`'s theadpool, which is by default set to 4. This means that Node cannot run more than 4 asynchronous operations in parallel, unless you change the `UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE` environment variable. There's no need for synchronization primitives like Mutexes (which is what this lock is) in a single-threaded environment.

Comment: most of the queue tasks will do async I/O, yeah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so this should satifsy the requirements, but it would nice to find a simpler way than this:

```
    const async = require('async');
    const q1 = async.queue((task, cb) => task(cb), 1);
    const q2 = async.queue((task, cb) => task(cb), 3);

    const map = new Map();
    let count = 0;

    const getProm = function (q) {

      if (!map.has(q)) {
        map.set(q, new Promise(resolve => {

          q1.push(cb => {
            resolve();  // 'lock' on q1 has been obtained, nothing can use q1 until we release the lock by calling cb().
            q.drain = () => {
              q.drain = null;
              count = 0;
              map.delete(q);
              cb();
            };
          });

        }));
      }

      return map.get(q);

    };


 if(foo && count < 5){
   return getProm(q2).then(v => {

      q2.push(cb => {
        setTimeout(cb, 140);
      });

    });
 }

 return q1.push(cb => {
      setTimeout(cb, 30);
    });
```

what this is doing is - only one type of task can run at a time, but if the type of task is foo, then 3 can run concurrently. The `count < 5` check ensures that q1 requests don't get starved by q2 requests.

The trick here is to use promises. Once a promise is resolved, you can still call `promise.then()`, with the resolution value, although we don't need that value in this case.

For slightly higher performance we could use boolean flags instead of promises, but the logic is a lot hairier there.